# MatExpansionPanel expression has changed after it was checked error 'mat-expanded: true'

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an Angular Material Expansion Panel Query list:

```
  @ViewChildren(MatExpansionPanel)
  matExpansionPanelQueryList: QueryList<MatExpansionPanel>;
```

and a simple array:

```
questions: [];
```

The Expansion Panels are generated with an `*ngFor`: simplified for example:

```
   <ng-container *ngFor="let question of questions>
            <mat-expansion-panel
               ...
```

When I extend the questions array, I want to open up the last expansion panel.

```
     extendQuestion() {
        this.matExpansionPanelQueryList.changes.subscribe(
          change => {
            change.last.open();
          }
        );

        this.questions.push('some-new-item');
      }
```

This works just fine - I insert an item to the array, 
the ExpansionPanels get's re-rendered, a new Panel gets created and it actually opens up - my problem is that it generates the following error in the console:

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has 
changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'mat-expanded: false'. Current 
value: 'mat-expanded: true'.
```

Is there any way to avoid this? 
I have tried using `changeDetectorRef` and `markForCheck()` in the subscription, but the error message did not go away (and honestly, I am 100% sure what's the exact problem here).

**Update**: [Stackblitz example of the issue (click the "+" button)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-3hm2z7)

Comment: please create a stackblitz demo

Comment: This might help to solve your issue and give you a good insight on [change detection operations](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)

Comment: @AbhishekKumar added an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [angularindepth](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4):

> This is a cautionary mechanism put in place to prevent inconsistencies between model data and UI so that erroneous or old data are not shown to a user on the page.

A running Angular application is a tree of components. During change detection Angular performs checks for each component which consists of the following operations performed in the specified order:

- update bound properties for all child components/directives
- call ngOnInit, OnChanges and ngDoCheck lifecycle hooks on all child components/directives
- update DOM for the current component
- run change detection for a child component
- call ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook for all child components/directives

After each operation Angular remembers what values it used to perform an operation. They are stored in the oldValues property of the component view.

You might want to trigger the lifecycle hook of your component before the DOM update operation..

That should work for you:

You can add a `constructor` for changedetection (cd) and call it after `change.last.open();`

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit, QueryList, ViewChildren} from '@angular/core';

import {MatDialog, MatExpansionPanel} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})

export class AppComponent {
questions = ['first', 'second'];

constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    }

@ViewChildren(MatExpansionPanel) matExpansionPanelQueryList: QueryList<MatExpansionPanel>;


extendQuestion() {
        this.matExpansionPanelQueryList.changes.subscribe(
        change => {
            change.last.open();
            this.cd.detectChanges();
        }
        );
        this.questions.push('some-new-item');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the infos, however, can you please elaborate on how to put this into practice in the exact problem? How to trigger "the lifecycle hook" (which one?) as I want to preform the operation after the new element gets rendered(as I am subscribed to the query list changes)?

Comment: give me a sec and i'll try to provide you with the actual code of your example

Comment: You post the exact same solution I wrote 15 minutes before your edit?

Comment: @ForestG was busy trying on stackblitz and didn't see you posted an answer already below since my edit-answer was still opened ;)

Comment: @ForestG anytime for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to the problem.

From the link that @iLuvLogix mentioned, forcing a change detection solved the issue:

```
    constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

    this.matExpansionPanelQueryList.changes.subscribe(
      change => {
        change.last.open();
        this.cd.detectChanges();
      }
    );
```

Comment: You might wanna accept my elaborate answer for futute reference if someone encounters the same issue  - köszönöm ;)