# Create a mat-accordion dynamically where new items are expanded by default

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a `mat-accordion`.  The expansion panels come from a list that changes over time.  When a new value is added I'd like it to be expanded by default.  I have my current attempt in this [stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-playground-zfbku3).

Repeated here:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-demo-one',
  templateUrl: './demo-one.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./demo-one.component.scss']
})
export class DemoOneComponent implements OnInit {

  items = [
    { name: 'name1', value: 'value1' }
  ]

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onAddItem() {
    this.items.push({name: 'new-item', value: 'new-value'});
  }

}

<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="true" *ngFor="let item of items">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>{{item.name}}</mat-expansion-panel-header>
    {{item.value}}
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
<button (click)="onAddItem()">Add Item</button>
```

This approach is based on https://github.com/angular/components/issues/6962 and this works except it creates change detection errors:

```
preview-1fc37597e512f64998bbb.js:1 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'mat-expanded: true'. Current value: 'mat-expanded: false'.
```

Comment: This answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54823152/matexpansionpanel-expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked-error-mat-expande

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at the below link/example, I have made changes, added `ChangeDetectorRef` to detect Changes

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-playground-pompat)

thanks

Comment: Classic example of why we require code to be included on Stack Overflow itself, rather than only on external sites. I am allowed to access Stack Overflow at work, but not StackBlitz. Thus, this answer is useless to me.